# How to run linux 0.01?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running linux kernel 0.01 in a virtual machine](https://superuser.com/questions/290808/running-linux-kernel-0-01-in-a-virtual-machine)

How can I run Linux 0.01 on my laptop?

If it's possible to run it, could you tell me how? Here you can [download the source code](http://kerneltrap.org/node/14002).

Comment: Pretty close duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/290808/running-linux-kernel-0-01-in-a-virtual-machine

Answer (score 10):

Linux 0.01 is very unlikely to work on modern hardware due to lack of driver support. Also, modern distros probably won't boot on ancient kernels because they need interfaces that weren't in the oldest Linuxes.

You'll want to install a 386 simulator such as Bochs, install an ancient Linux distro such as SLS or early Debian/Slackware on it, then try to replace the kernel with 0.01.

Comment: Agreed, if you're gonna be a masochist and go for this, then indeed, use a Virtual Machine of sorts for it. KVM could do it. I also like VMware's products for this.

Answer (score 6):

Read [the release notes on the page you linked to](http://kerneltrap.org/node/14002) and read [The Linux Kernel 0.01 Commentary](http://pramode2.tripod.com/kerneldocs/kc.ps.gz). You'll need a machine with a floppy drive, a legacy IDE controller (or a pretty good imitation), a hard drive you can repartition at will, old compiler and assembler versions, and probably some low-level knowledge to hack around hardware quirks that Linux 0.01 couldn't imagine. Note that that document was written in 2003, and as much has changed from 2003 to 2011 as between 1994 and 2003.